# Configuring dynamic height for Table Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have some lag issue with this method tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

My scenario as follows: 
I have some textviews in each of the cell so I need to loop through the cell to get the yPosition of the last textview and its content size in order to configure the height for that particular cell.

In order to do so, I used UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; in heightForRowAtIndexPath method. So that it does is, it calls cellForRow and reconfigure the content of my cell and return back to me.

However, this is where the lag issue occurs. Since heightForRow will be called before the actual cellForRow, it means that I will be calling cellForRow twice. One in heightForRow in order to get the cell and another for the actual cellForRow implementation.

Kindly advice on what I need to do in order to avoid this lag issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate row height at your `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, by calling `-[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]` or some other API alike, and adding any padding heights to it.

However fast you do it in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, there is still a penalty compared with `tableView.rowHeight`.

Comment: There are several textview inside this cell, so you were suggesting that I should get the text from each textview and append them together as string and then use -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:] to get the height for the cell? Correct me if Im wrong. Thank you.

Comment: If the texts are not modified very often, you can even cache those heights.

Comment: yea thats what im doing it right now, having an array to store all the heights of each cells. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should never be calling table view delegate methods on your own. You can tell the table view to reload its data with this: `[tableview reloadData];`

Comment: reloadData in this case does not help since the height is not configure yet. Thanks for your reply, really appreciate it